# MultiHttpMock Responses

Tags: unit-test, httpcalloutmock

I have a class with makes multi http callouts. For testing the class I created a test class and it doesn't respond as expected.

```
@isTest
public class G_MockResponse implements HttpCalloutMock {

    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        HTTPResponse res = new HTTPResponse();
        res.setStatusCode(200);

        if (req.getEndpoint().endsWith('/login_information')) { 
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"status":"res1"}');

        } else if (req.getEndpoint().endsWith('/els')) { 
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"status":"res1"}');

        } else if (req.getEndpoint().endsWith('/rr')) { 
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"status":"res1"}');

        } else if (req.getEndpoint().endsWith('/dc')) { 
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
            res.setBody('');
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Class to test

```
 public String getBaseURL() {
        if(this.baseUrl == null) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            Http http = new Http();      
            req.setEndpoint(this.loginUrl);  //login_information 
            req.setTimeout(this.timeout);
            req.setMethod('GET');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setHeader('X-Authentication', this.getAuthHeader());
            if(this.errorCode == null) {
                res = http.send(req); 
                if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                 ...
```

When I run my test class the coverage always stops when the request is being sent. Seems like my code fails to get response from the MockHttpCallout class.

Is this a good approach for handling multiple callouts?

Comment: I would add a constructor into your multiMock class so you can pass in a map of endPoints and statusCodes in `Test.setMock(..)` so your mock can return status code of 200 vs non-200 and you can test your code for error handling. Right now, every mock response is always a success (200) as you've defined it

Answer (score 1):

In the test class you would need to add the Mock class as well:

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new G_MockResponse());
```

So, it should be:

```
 public String getBaseURL() {
        if(this.baseUrl == null) {

            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new G_MockResponse());

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            Http http = new Http();      
            req.setEndpoint(this.loginUrl);  //login_information 
            req.setTimeout(this.timeout);
            req.setMethod('GET');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setHeader('X-Authentication', this.getAuthHeader());
            if(this.errorCode == null) {
                res = http.send(req); 
                if(res.getStatusCode() == 200) {
```

Reference: [Mock Callout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm)

Comment: I didn't put code for my test class. Yes in test class I added the Mock Class.

I am more concern about, is this a good approach for multiple http callouts?
If yes, any ideas why it fails when sending the request?

Comment: @vsomani yes this is a good approach. It has no issue with the design. You would have some logical error that your code is not working. Your code seems fine.